# Size doesn't work with HTML5 Input tag

Tags: html

For below code, the size value is ignored. Any help is appreciated?

```
<p><input type="submit" name="login" id="login" value="Login" size="125"/> </p>
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

it's for [text, password or file input field](http://reference.sitepoint.com/html/input/size)

> The size attribute is used to set the width of a text, password or file input field. The length of these fields is determined by the number of characters that should be visible
>
> For all other input types, the size refers to the width of the control in pixels. **Given the presentational nature of this attribute, it’s usually best avoided.** Instead, use CSS to define field widths using more precise measurements, with the exception of a file input where CSS control over the input’s appearance is severely limited (for very valid security reasons) and the size attribute is your only real option.

Comment: I was absolutely not paying attention and did not realize his input was of type submit.  +1